# Intent.addFlags using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, android-intent

Does adding flags to an intent using a for loop, overwrite the previous flag added in the loop?

**Example 1:**

What I want to achieve

```
int[] flags = {Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK};

for (int flag: flags) {
     intent.addFlags(flag);
}
```

**Example 2:**

How flags are normally added

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

**Example 3:**

Simple code representation of the for loop in Example 1

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

**REASON:**

**Example 4:**

I am passing flags into a method

```
public void startActivity(int[] flags) {
      for (int flag: flags) {
          intent.addFlags(flag);
      }
}
```

**Resolution:**

If a for loop does overwrite the previously added flag, how can I achieve the code seen in Example 2 using the method seen in Example 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not actually familiar with android Intent, but it seems you're simply combining bits stored in integers, so you could do something like this:

```
int combinedFlags = 0;
for (int flag : flags) {
    combinedFlags |= flag;
}
intent.addFlags(combinedFlags);
```